# Need to disable specific checkbox on selected mode with tree expansion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had checkbox tree view, which which i need to disable first two checkbox with selected mode. I can able to do that with help of `checked` and `readonly` properties, but i can able to uncheck the checkbox which is not my requirement.

Note : Even i tried with `checked` and `disable` properties, if i use disable, it collapse its child nodes.

How to fix it.

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uU82C/14/

My try code :

`checked` and `readonly`

```
var completeTreeView ="<div id='treeview-id' class='css-treeview'><ul><li><input type='checkbox' id=GrandParent checked readonly/><label1 for='item-0'>Grand Parent</label1><ul><li><input type='checkbox' id='parent' checked readonly/><label2 for='item-0'>parent</label2>";
```

`checked` and `disable`

```
var completeTreeView ="<div id='treeview-id' class='css-treeview'><ul><li><input type='checkbox' id=GrandParent checked disable/><label1 for='item-0'>Grand Parent</label1><ul><li><input type='checkbox' id='parent' checked disable/><label2 for='item-0'>parent</label2>";
```

Please help in out of this.

Comment: check if this helps. i just used the jquery `prop` method.http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/4DqXv/891/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i modified the sample for you. Hope it may helpful for you. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>        
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[name="level-1"],input[name="level-2"]').bind('click', function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', ($(this).is(':checked')));
    });

    $('input[name="level-1"],input[name="level-2"]').change(function(e) {
        $(e.target).prop({disabled:true});
    });

    $('input[name="level-1"],input[name="level-2"]').trigger('change');

});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="level-1">Grand Parent</input>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level-2">parent</input>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="level-3">child 1</input>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="level-3">child 2</input>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="level-3">child 3</input>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="level-3">Level 3</input>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/W5KKV/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your post. Still this is not my requirement @Jeba. My plm is grand parent and parents should be checked default and it should not be allowed to unselect again. In your example i can able to unselect the nodes.

Comment: @Hariharan, Please check the updated source. Its working fine for me. Please check and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: But i need it in javascript. I will try myself. If im unable to get i will ask for help.

Comment: Can i get answer in javascript ?

Comment: @Hariharan,, Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/uU82C/16/. i updated your code. Its working fine. Please check it once again and let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Hariharan, did you check the updated javascript answer http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/uU82C/16/. Please check and let me know... Thanks